# filter rows based on column values in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql query

```
SELECT a.model_name, 
       IF( b.officially_released_year = '".$currentyear."',1,0 ) AS release_year, 
       IF( b.officially_released_month = '".$first_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$second_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$third_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$currentmonth."' ,1,0) AS release_month 
FROM ".TBL_CAR_ADD_MODELS." a, ".TBL_CAR_SPEC_GENERAL." b 
WHERE a.model_id = b.model_id AND a.model_status = '1' 
ORDER BY a.model_created_on DESC
```

I want to do one more filtering option in this query. I need to get the records based on release_year = 1 & release_year = 1. I have done release_year and release_month columns through IF STATEMENT in MYSQL QUERY

release_year

```
IF( b.officially_released_year = '".$currentyear."',1,0 ) AS release_year
```

release_month

```
IF( b.officially_released_month = '".$first_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$second_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$third_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$currentmonth."' ,1,0) AS release_month
```

How do I get the records based on these values (release_month = 1 & release_year = 1) in this query? I have tried `WHERE release_month = 1 AND release_year = 1` but this one returns unknown column

Comment: You could make your current query a sub-query and _then_ use that `WHERE` clause on the outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
SELECT 
    a.model_name,
    a.model_created_on, 
    IF( b.officially_released_year = '".$currentyear."',1,0 ) AS release_year, 
    IF( b.officially_released_month = '".$first_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$second_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$third_month."' OR b.officially_released_month = '".$currentmonth."' ,1,0) AS release_month 
FROM ".TBL_CAR_ADD_MODELS." a, ".TBL_CAR_SPEC_GENERAL." b 
WHERE a.model_id = b.model_id AND a.model_status = '1' 

) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.release_year=1 AND release_month=1
ORDER BY tbl.model_created_on DESC
```