# Dynamic assign value type filter in codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Dynamic assign value type where query not working, showing error "database error" Unknown column 'avgRateVal' in 'where clause'. What is the best possible to to do it, any advice

```
$this->db->select('round(avg(ratevalue),1) as avgRateVal');
if($minRating!=0)
    $this->db->where('avgRateVal >=', 1);

if($maxRating!=0)
    $this->db->where('avgRateVal <=', 5);
```

Comment: got solution for sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160875/filter-rows-based-on-column-values-in-mysql-query but how to implement in codeigniter, any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Write your query like this:

```
$this->db->select('round(avg(ratevalue),1) as avgRateVal');
if($minRating!=0)
     $this->db->having('avgRateVal >=', 1);

if($maxRating!=0)
     $this->db->having('avgRateVal <=', 5);
$this->db->get('Table_Name');
$this->db->result_array();
```

Comment: read this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html  you can get better idea about codeigniter active records @santanu

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nidhi

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->select('round(avg(ratevalue),1) as avgRateVal');

if($minRating!=0)

```
$this->db->where('round(avg(ratevalue),1) >=', 1);
```

if($maxRating!=0)

```
$this->db->where('round(avg(ratevalue),1) <=', 5);
```

Comment: tried that already , it's not working as it's showing database error - Invalid use of group function